# C# Нажатие кнопки на клавиатуре по истечению времени

Tags: c#, winforms

```
if (minInterval == 0 && sec == 0)
{
    timer1.Enabled = false; //по истечению времени таймер отключается
    if (checkBox1.Checked == true) //тут если стоит галочка, то мы должны нажать кнопку ПРОБЕЛ
    {
    нажатие на кнопку пробел (пробел требуется нажать не обязательно в форме, а вообще везде типа), хочу организовать паузу при просмотре фильма online например, как раз по истечению времени
    }
    //если галка не стоит, то идет код дальше
    FORM2.ShowDialog();
    timer1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Что значит "мы должны нажать кнопку ПРОБЕЛ"? Программа должна сэмулировать нажатие клавиши? Отправить нажатие в другое приложение?

Comment: да типа того, там я пробовал keysend.send("{enter}"), как-то так, но пробела нет в ней

Comment: Не, вы должны доставить сначала фокус приложению, которому собираетесь послать нажатие. Нельзя послать «просто нажатие», ваше нажатие шлётся приложению, у которого фокус.

Comment: можете показать пример? именно с "пробелом"

Answer (score 0):

Нужно послать окну сообщение о нажатии клавиши, например так:

```
SendMessage(FindWindow(NULL, 'Notepad'), WM_KEYDOWN, VK_SPACE, 0)
```

Затем через некоторое время об отпускании клавиши, например так:

```
SendMessage(FindWindow(NULL, 'Notepad'), WM_KEYUP, VK_SPACE, 0)
```

Comment: Смогу проверить завтра тока, а как сделать для браузера? каждое название вписывать (яндекс, гугл, опера, мозила и другие)?

Comment: вообще не работает